# Writing Parser for Integer - Type Error

Tags: haskell

Given the following `Parser` definitions (from Prof. Brent Yorgey's U of Penn [class](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~cis194/spring13/)):

```
newtype Parser a = Parser { runParser :: String -> Maybe (a, String) }

satisfy :: (Char -> Bool) -> Parser Char
satisfy p = Parser f
  where
    f [] = Nothing    -- fail on the empty input
    f (x:xs)          -- check if x satisfies the predicate
                        -- if so, return x along with the remainder
                        -- of the input (that is, xs)
        | p x       = Just (x, xs)
        | otherwise = Nothing  -- otherwise, fail
```

Given the following parser for `one or more of 'a'`:

```
oneOrMore :: Parser a -> Parser [a]
oneOrMore p = (:) <$> p <*> (zeroOrMore p)
```

And, now I'd like to extract an `Integer` or nothing:

```
parseInteger :: String -> Maybe Integer
parseInteger = fmap (read . fst) $ runParser (oneOrMore (satisfy isNumber))
```

But I'm getting this compile-time error:

```
JsonParser.hs:42:36:
    Couldn't match type ‘(String, b0)’ with ‘Maybe ([Char], String)’
    Expected type: String -> (String, b0)
      Actual type: String -> Maybe ([Char], String)
    In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely
      ‘runParser (oneOrMore (satisfy isNumber))’
    In the expression:
      fmap (read . fst) $ runParser (oneOrMore (satisfy isNumber))
Failed, modules loaded: SExpr, Model, AParser.
*SExpr Data.Char> :t runParser 
runParser :: Parser a -> String -> Maybe (a, String)
```

I'm confused since `runParser` has a type of `String -> Maybe (a, String)`.

Calling `fmap` on `Maybe (a, String)` should apply `fmap`'s function to the `(a, String)` type.

What am I missing?

Comment: You are not asking for this, but the approach used in `parseInteger` is weird -- I would say even morally wrong. This is because it breaks the `Parser` abstraction with `runParser`, and the result is not a `Parser` so it is not composable with anything else. A more natural approach would be to provide a `Functor Parser` instance, and then define `integer :: Parser Integer` as `fmap read $ oneOrMore (satisfy isNumber)`. In this way you keep everything "inside" the parser functor, and the result is a parser which can then be reused compositionally.

Comment: Thank you for setting me straight, chi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `(.)` instead of `$`:

```
fmap (read . fst) . runParser (oneOrMore (satisfy isNumber))
```

alternatively you need to supply the string to `runParser`:

```
parseInteger s = fmap (read . fst) $ runParser (oneOrMore (satisfy isNumber)) s
```

`fmap (read . fst)` in this case has type `Maybe (String, a) -> Maybe Integer` and `runParser (oneOrMore (satisfy isNumber))` has type `String -> Maybe (String, String)`. These two functions can be composed with `(.)`, but `($)` has type `(a -> b) -> a -> b` - here `a` is `Maybe (String, a)` while you are supplying the function inside the `Parser`.

If you apply the string to this function instead, you can get the `Maybe (String, a)` required by `($)`.

Comment: @KevinMeredith - `$` is used to apply arguments to functions while `(.)` is used to compose them - you will usually use `(.)` in point-free style.